# Apply StringIndexer PySpark Dataframe but ordered alphabetically

Tags: pyspark

How can I apply the indexer in pyspark, but ordered the categories alphabetically?

I have my dictionary of the indexed values, after applying the Stringindexer but I would like to order it differently.

```
index_df = StringIndexer(inputCol="gender", outputCol="genderIndex")

meta = [f.metadata for f in index_df.schema.fields if f.name == "genderIndex"]
meta
[{u'ml_attr': {u'name': u'genderIndex',
   u'type': u'nominal',
   u'vals': [u'Male', u'Female']}}]

a=dict(enumerate(meta[0]["ml_attr"]["vals"]))
a=
{0: u'Male', 1: u'Female'}
```

But For example, I want female to be 0, and if it was a,b ,c

I would like a=0, b=1, c=2,etc...

Comment: StringIndexer provides indices to column labels based on label frequency. For your case, think we may have to code custom transformer to do it.

Comment: I don't know your usecase, but if you are going to save the indexed column to dictionary and not going to use it for ML pipeline, then order the column and do dense rank. This might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spark 2.3.0 spark's StringIndexer will get `stringOrderType` parameter ([related jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20619)), but in <2.3.0 you will need to create custom transformer. For example you can gater all values, add index and join with initial df, like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([(10, 'b'), (20, 'b'), (30, 'c'), 
                            (40, 'c'), (50, 'c'), (60, 'a')], ['col1', 'col2'])
col2_index = df.select('col2').distinct() \
    .withColumn('col2Index', row_number().over(Window.orderBy('col2')) - 1)
col2_index.show()

+----+---------+
|col2|col2Index|
+----+---------+
|   a|        0|
|   b|        1|
|   c|        2|
+----+---------+

df.join(col2_index, 'col2').show()

+----+----+---------+
|col2|col1|col2Index|
+----+----+---------+
|   c|  30|        2|
|   c|  40|        2|
|   c|  50|        2|
|   b|  10|        1|
|   b|  20|        1|
|   a|  60|        0|
+----+----+---------+
```

**OR** if you do not care about having transformers dictionary created, you can just use `dense_rank` as @Suresh noticed in the comments:

```
df.withColumn('col2Index', dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy('col2')) - 1).show()
```

Comment: Is there way easier way to extract and customized transformers fitted dictionary?

Comment: @haneulkim You can extract labels using `string_indexer_model.labels`, but I don't think you can customize it easily. You can persisting the model, modifying file and loading it back.